# How do you load an ed25519 key string into nodejs?

Tags: node.js, public-key-encryption, ed25519

I can generate a key with crypto.generateKeyPairSync()

But how do I go about loading it from a string/file?

Comment: Use the buil-in `fs` module... The node.js documention is pretty well done, feel free to read it.

Comment: The export is possible with [`export()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#keyobjectexportoptions), the import with [`createPrivateKey()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreateprivatekeykey) or [`createPublicKey()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatepublickeykey). In addition, the key can be imported _directly_ into [`sign()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptosignalgorithm-data-key-callback) or [`verify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptoverifyalgorithm-data-key-signature-callback).